# php code is working in laravel view files but core simple laravel code is not in laravel view file (laravel version:5.2.45)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In laravel view file:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
       <p class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
@endif
```

above code not working, its getting display on view file as it is..

But I am using simple php instead of that:

```
<?php if (Session::has('success')){ ?>
   <p class="alert alert-info"><?php echo Session::get('success'); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Its working properly.. then why this is happning

php code is working properly but simple laravel code is not working in laravel view/blade file.. its getting printed on view page as it is..

please clarify this..

Comment: Is your extension correct? (`your-view.blade.php`)

Comment: are all other blade commands like {{ 'test string' }} working?

Comment: %99.9 your extension does not have blade word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your view file extension wrong please correct you view file like `index.blade.php`

Comment: @Amita Glad to help and if my answer is your solution then please accept and upvote to my answer

Comment: i convert all my project view file's extensions from ".php" to ".blade.php".... really though its working fine.. means php code works fine in laravel.. then we can work with php code in laravel instead of laravel code style.. is it ok??

Comment: @Amita Its ok and its work but first prefer laravel code structure otherwise no meaning of use framework

Comment: @Amita If any question then as me

Comment: may i know what will be the disadvantages if we use php coding in laravel view files

Comment: @Amita your core php code work fine in laravel but when you use core php code in laravel then more time consuming for load the page